# Rails is returning an instance of User instead of a user Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I recently deployed my site on Heroku and Netlify and was having issues with Auth. My current issue (and hopefully last) is that upon login, rails is sending back a user instance instead of the object with information (i.e #User:0x000056205efbbad8). I get a token from my rails response and upon refresh am logged in but am not automatically logged in because of the user instance being returned instead of an object with user information.
This is my auth controller

```
class AuthController < ApplicationController

    def login
        user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
            if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
                secret = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
                token = JWT.encode({ user_id: user.id }, secret, 'HS256')
                
                render json: { user: UserSerializer.new(user), token: token }
            else
                render json: { failure: "Invalid Username or Password" }
            end
    end

    def signup
        auth_params = params.permit(:username, :password, :email, :avatar)
        if params[:avatar].instance_of?(String) || params[:avatar].nil?
            user = User.create(auth_params)
            render json: user
        else 
            imageUploaded = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:avatar])
            user_params_new = auth_params
            user_params_new[:avatar] = imageUploaded["url"]
            user = User.create(user_params_new)
            if user.valid?
                secret = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
                token = JWT.encode({ user_id: user.id }, secret, 'HS256')
                render json: {user: user, token: token }, status: :created
            else 
                render json: { error: user.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Here is my login function on my React frontend

```
function handleLogin(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/login`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(loginData)
        })
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.failure) {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Oops...',
                    text: 'Incorrect Username or Password!'
                  })
            } else {
            setCurrentUser(data.user)
            setUserReviews(data.user.reviews)
            setFavorites(data.user.favorites)
            localStorage.setItem("token", data.token)
            history.push("/festivals")
            }
        })
    }
```

I so appreciate any help on this, thanks so much!

Link to github repo: https://github.com/connormul/festie-backend
https://github.com/connormul/festie-frontend

Answer (score 0):

```
render json: { user: UserSerializer.new(user), token: token }
```

This doesn't look a correct use of serializer
try to change it to

```
render json: { user: UserSerializer.new(user).as_json, token: token }
```